# What type of problem is this? Combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given 10 cups and 8 non-distinct balls, how many ways can we distribute the balls among the cups such that no cup has more than 2 balls in it? Cups are allowed to be empty, as required by the problem statement.

I've seen examples of placing items in containers, but rarely when the number of containers is greater than the number of items and never when a maximum number of items is specified per container. What type of formula or mathematics can I use? My first thought was to use the binomial coefficient of "n choose k", but that only works for n>k. Also, I don't know how to factor in the limit per container. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)

Comment: Alternatively, how many ways can you partition 8 into sums of $1$s and $2$s?

Comment: Yes, it is combinatorics. but the (Probability) tag is unnecessary.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish, there are $f(8)=34$ ways to do so. Where $f(n)$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number with $f(0)=1, f(1)=1$ and $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2), n\ge2$.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish: Related to sum of $1$'s and $2$'s, but we also have $0$'s.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Yes, when you we take the partitions say $1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1$ or $1+2+1+2+1+1$, then there are $2$ and $4$ cups are empty respectively, and there are other cases too. So in this way, the $0$ cases are also counted.

Comment: With indistinguishable cups we can ignore the 0s.

Comment: With indistinguishable cups we can indeed ignore. There is some ambiguity in the problem. Because they mentioned explicitly that the balls were indistinguishable, but did not say it for the cups, I interpreted the problem as being about distinguishable cups.

Comment: @AndréNicolas that is probably a more realistic assumption, and it certainly makes the problem more manageable! (although, this particular flavor of partition is not too difficult to count)

Comment: I have access to quite a few math books in a library. What type of book, chapter, or subject would I most benefit from to solve this? I don't really want to just dive into a combinatorics book, since I think I'd be lost. If I knew what subject to look for in a combinatorics book, I may be able to start.

Answer (score 3):

I preassume that the cups are distinguishable.

Discern the cases:

- $8=4\times2+0\times1+6\times0$
- $8=3\times2+2\times1+5\times0$
- $8=2\times2+4\times1+4\times0$
- $8=1\times2+6\times1+3\times0$
- $8=0\times2+8\times1+2\times0$

Final answer is: $$\frac{10!}{4!0!6!}+\frac{10!}{3!2!5!}+\frac{10!}{2!4!4!}+\frac{10!}{1!6!3!}+\frac{10!}{0!8!2!}$$

Comment: I'm still not seeing the connection. Could you give a bit more intuition behind it? I like where this is going.

Comment: @TrekGeek1 Splitting up $8$ as $8=3\times2+2\times1+5\times0$ (second bullet in answer) corresponds with: $3$ from the $10$ cups must be selected to contain $2$ balls, $2$ must be selected to contain $1$ ball and $5$ to contain the $0$ balls. There are $\frac{10!}{3!2!5!}$ possible selections (second term in final answer).

Answer (score 1):

There are much smarter ways to do it, but full enumeration works too. There are $\binom{10}{4}$ ways to select the cups if 2 balls go ibto each and $\binom{10}{8}$ if exactly 1 goes into each. These are boundary cases. To get from the former to the latter, just start by rsmoving 1 ball from any cup. What do you get?

Comment: What are the smarter ways?

Comment: Recurrences, generating fs

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this using generating functions. Each cup can have 0, 1, or 2 balls and the total number of balls should be 8.

For each cup we associate the polynomial $(1+x+x^2)$ and multiply ten such terms together (one for each cup). So the expression we have is $(1+x+x^2)^{10}$. If you expand this out without simplifying, a term $x^k$ comes from a choice of 1, $x$, or $x^2$ from the first cup, a choice from the second cup, etc. And so $x^k$ represents one way of putting $k$ balls into 10 cups. (Try doing this with smaller numbers).

Simplifying the expression (i.e., write it as $a_0 + a_1x+ \dots + a_{20}x^{20}$), we see that the coefficient of $x^k$ is the number of ways of putting $k$ balls into 10 cups. So the coefficient of $x^8$ tells you how many ways you can put 8 balls into 10 cups. (You can come up with relatively short formula for computing this coefficient).

While this is not the shortest or simplest way of solving this problem, it is a very useful technique.